# Bubble Sort for Linked List HELP please

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

I am having some issues with my code and need to see if you can help.
I am trying to bubble sort my ROOM Struct and the code is below.
Pretty much, Room 1 Name: z ... Room 2 Name : a, i want sort these so it displays A, B etc.

The Issue: When I output the Linked List, this sort is making certain nodes dissapear.. for example after it sorts Z > A and puts at at the TOP, A is now gone when i go to print out my linked lists

Thanks for all help!

```
 void sortRoomsByName(int count, ROOM *head)
{
int i;
int j;

for(i = count ; i > 1 ; i-- ) //outer loop
{
    ROOM *temp;
    ROOM *swap1;

    swap1 = head;
    for(j = 0 ; j < count-1 ; j++ ) //inner loop
    {
        if(strcmp(swap1->roomName,swap1->nextRoom->roomName)<0) //compares names and swaps
        {
            ROOM *swap2;
            swap2 = swap1->nextRoom;
            swap1->nextRoom = swap2->nextRoom;
            swap2->nextRoom = swap1;
            if(swap1 == head)
            {
                head = swap2;
                swap1 = swap2;
            }
            else
            {
                swap1 = swap2;
                temp->nextRoom = swap2;
            }
        }
        temp = swap1;
        swap1 = swap1->nextRoom;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: So... whats wrong with this code? Wrong result or some memory problems?

Comment: when i output my linked list, its pretty much putting Z at the top and A is dissapearing.

Comment: Seems like you are building your loops wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

```
void sortRoomsByName(int count, ROOM *head)
{
int i;
int j;

for(i = 0 ; i < count - 1 ; i ++ ) //outer loop
{
    ROOM *swap1;

    swap1 = head;
    for(j = 0 ; j < count - i - 1 ; j ++ ) //inner loop
    {
        if(strcmp(swap1->roomName,swap1->nextRoom->roomName)<0) //compares names and swaps
        {
            ROOM *swap2;
            swap2 = swap1->nextRoom;
            swap1->nextRoom = swap2->nextRoom;
            swap2->nextRoom = swap1;
            if(swap1 == head)
            {
                head = swap2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            swap1 = swap1->nextRoom;
        }
    }
}
```

If no swaping is done then you have to jump to next NODE, I Hope this helps...

**EDIT:**
Remove Head from function argument and make it global or pass it like as follow..

```
void sortRoomsByName(int count, ROOM **head)
{
int i;
int j;

for(i = 0 ; i < count - 1 ; i ++ ) //outer loop
{
    ROOM *swap1;

    swap1 = *head;
    for(j = 0 ; j < count - i - 1 ; j ++ ) //inner loop
    {
        if(strcmp(swap1->roomName,swap1->nextRoom->roomName)<0) //compares names and swaps
        {
            ROOM *swap2;
            swap2 = swap1->nextRoom;
            swap1->nextRoom = swap2->nextRoom;
            swap2->nextRoom = swap1;
            if(swap1 == head)
            {
                *head = swap2;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            swap1 = swap1->nextRoom;
        }
    }
}

int main (void)
{
    sortRoomsByName(count /* your variable */, &head /* your head pointer */);
}
```

Comment: Its still giving the same issue, deleting the node?

Comment: Can you please put some code that how you are calling it.. and where you declare the head pointer.